# Code changes I should do to avoid piracy while distributing my app through Mac App Store?

Tags: cocoa, macos, app-store, mac-app-store

I am about submit our game to Mac App Store. What are the code changes I should do to avoid piracy (copy-protection) ?

Are there anything else apart from that I should do (Other than signing my app with their provision profile?) before I submit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should [validate the App Store receipt](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/mac/documents/validating.html).

Note that there is deliberately no code that you can just copy and paste into your app to do this: that's so that each app does the validation slightly differently, meaning crackers can't just patch one single version of the validation code.

There's more information on the Apple developer forums.

Comment: -1 Your link leads to a protected page that only Mac Dev centre registered users can use.

Comment: Anyone who is going to be submitting an app to the Mac App Store is a registered developer. I don't know of any other documentation on receipt validation.

Comment: But this is a web site for anybody to read.  People who are only thinking of signing up for the program are likely to want to read your answer, which doesn't really tell them anything.

Comment: And it's confidential information, so I can't really tell them anything. In that case, would you suggest I had posted no answer at all?